# Force of mortality

Tags: probability, statistics

[image]

The force of morality (hazard rate) at time $t$ is $\mu(t)$, so why does the expresion in the question denote the average force of mortality?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general if $f$ is a function then $\frac{1}{b-a}\int_a^b f(t)dt$ is the average of $f$ on $[a;b]$.